# discord.py Get the ban reason of a banned user

Tags: python, discord.py

I made a Discord bot using Python which will have simple commands like "kick", "ban", "mute", "warn" etc. I also want to add "list warns" and "list bans" commands.

I can get all banned users with below code:

```py
bans = await client.get_bans(message.guild.id)
for user in bans:
    print(f"User: {user.name} | User ID: {user.id}")
```

But in Discord, ban reason is also saved when banning a member:

[image]

How can I retrieve the ban reason from a banned user? I couldn't find anything related to this in discord.py documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of client.get_bans() use guild.bans().
Getting a reason is also simple.
Useful information: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=bans#discord.BanEntry

Here is my code:

```py
bans = await message.guild.bans() #Getting a list of all ban entries
for ban_entry in bans: #Looping through all entries
   user = ban_entry.user #Getting user
   reason = ban_entry.reason #Getting Reason
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and an example!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [bans()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=guild%20ban#discord.Guild.bans) method.

`await guild.bans()` => It returns `BanEntry` object.
And this object contains two properties are [**Reason**](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=guild%20ban#discord.BanEntry.reason) and **User**.

Answer (score 0):

which version of the library are you using?

the `client.get_bans()` returns a list of `guild.Ban`, which does come with `user` and `reason`:

```
    def get_bans(self, guild_id: Snowflake) -> Response[List[guild.Ban]]:
        return self.request(Route('GET', '/guilds/{guild_id}/bans', guild_id=guild_id))
```

```
class Ban(TypedDict):
    reason: Optional[str]
    user: User
```

see https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/45d498c1b76deaf3b394d17ccf56112fa691d160/discord/http.py#L1119

so, maybe something like

```
bans = await client.get_bans(message.guild.id)
for ban in bans:
    user = ban['user']
    reason = ban['reason']
```

Comment: `client.get_bans()` is outdated (< v1.0)